# How to delete multiple folders together

Tags: applescript

Instead of doing

```
 if exists folder1 then
       delete folder1
 end if

 if exists folder2 then
       delete folder2
 end if

 ...
 ...
```

Is there a way to do:

```
 delete folder1 folder2 ... folderN
```

Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how you're setting folder1, folder2, etc, but assuming those variables are already set, here's how to use the list and repeat iterate through the list.

```
set folderList to {folder1, folder2}
repeat with thisFolder in folderList
    delete thisFolder
end repeat
```